# Identifying parents of Adelhaid Marx (died 1920/45) of rabbinic family from western Germany?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, baptism-records, jewish

My great-great-grandmother, Adelheid Marx was a descendant of the Marx rabbinic family from western Germany. Her husband was Albert Westheim (d c. 1915) and her children include my great-grandmother, Elsa Mühlgay (*née* Westheim [unknown-1981]) and son/step-son, [Paul Westheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Westheim).

We think that this Marx family is the same as Karl's for what it's worth.

Family stories and family records provide two conflicting death dates of  c.1920 and 1945 and disagree on the place.

How can I identify the parents of Adelhaid Marx?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl, this is about all the information I have, hence my desire to find out more.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl, I wish. I don't know her parents' names.

Comment: Such a wide difference between 2 possible death dates suggests that either something has been misinterpreted or that some of the records don't apply to your person. I suggest that you start by re-evaluating what you have, in order to determine how to weight the conflicting evidence.

Comment: @bgwiehle, that's the problem. All I have are those two conflicting death dates, informed from family stories and records which disagree on the **date** and **place** of death. Unfortunately, AFAIK, there isn't anyone living who could clarify this for me.

Comment: "Adelheid Marx (died c.1920 or 1945, depending on the record) from Western Germany. What do You mean with Western Germany ? Without an area, town/village, it's impossible, to find details

Comment: To progress this perhaps you can include the name, place and date of birth/baptism for the child of Adelheid that you descend from.  From there you may be able to work forward to where/when he is more likely to have died and backwards to seek a marriage record, and eventually a birth/baptism record.  What are the two candidate places of death that you have (matched to those two dates)?

Comment: @Wolff99, according to family lore, she spent the war in England and died in London after seeing my great-grandmother ע”ה again in 1945.

Comment: I have an account of a Marx boy of roughly 11 or 12 years running away from home in the Hamburg/Altona area, he boarded an American Merchant ship with my Great Grandfather J H Samuel and another boy, unknown , but of similar age, they jumped ship together illegally in South Africa (Port Alfred)in 1876 after about 20 years as sailors, they split up afterwards when Marx went to join the Reef Goldrush.I dont know if this has any connection to your family.

Comment: Who was she married to? what was her Married name? or did she marry into the marx family

Comment: Why don't you start by telling us her children

Comment: Make sure you check [JewishGen's Rabbinic SIG](https://www.jewishgen.org/Rabbinic/) can be of help.